# Pass data in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I encountered problems when pass data in navigation drawer.
I have an Menu using navigation. First MainMenu load fragment NewRadioFragment get some data from service. When NewRadioFragment have data, I want send data to fragment PlayRadio, Viewpager contain two fragment PlayRadio and BlogContent through ViewPagerActivity. I tried use Communicate in NewRadioFragment but data send to MainMenu and don't send to PlayRadio.
I need help ! if you have solution pls give me...

Thanks all.

Sorry ! i speak English not good if my question inexactness please edit it.

Here! My code

**public class NewRadioFragment extends Fragment**

```
public interface ReturnData {
        public void sendData(String result);
    }

btnShowMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (item.getLink_play() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, item.getLink_play(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mCallBack.sendData(Desciption);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallBack = (ReturnData) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ReturnData");
        }
    }
```

**public class PlayBlog extends Fragment implements ReturnData**

```
@Override
    public void sendData(String result) {
        //Here not have data
        Log.i("", Constant.TAG +"PlayBlog "+ result);
    }
```

MainMenu use config Navigation Drawer

**public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity implements ReturnData**

```
@Override
    public void sendData(String result) {
        // But here have data
        Log.i("", Constant.TAG+"MainMenu " + result);
    }
```